# Execute CompletableFuture which depends on an other task

Tags: java, asynchronous, playframework, completable-future

I wrote a Play framework web application and I have the following problem. I have some DAOs that access the database, and sometimes one request to the database relies on information from another request.

Here is one of the problems: I execute the `getLicenseByKey` method in an asynchronous way and get the result. Now I can execute `version_dao.getVersionUntilX()` with the result of the `license_dao` request. The problem here is that the `.get()` function of `CompletableFuture` is executed on the `HttpExecutionContext` (blocking one of the HTTP threads of Akka (Play framework)), and if this database request takes a long time, the thread is blocked.

So how can I execute asynchronously the `license_dao.getLicenseByKey()` and then, with the result of this method, execute the `version_dao.getVersionUntilX()` method also asynchronously? And if both are finished, I want to return the HTTP result from the `HttpExecutionContext` of Play.

```
public CompletionStage<Result> showDownloadScreen(String license_key) {
    return license_dao.getLicenseByKey(license_key).thenApplyAsync(license -> {
        try {
            if(license!=null) {

                if(license.isRegistered()) {
                    return ok(views.html.download.render(license, 
                        version_dao.getVersionUntilX(license.getUpdates_until())
                        .toCompletableFuture().get()));
                }else {
                    return redirect(routes.LicenseActivationController.showActivationScreen(license_key));
                }
            }else {
                return redirect(routes.IndexController.index("Insert Key can not be found!"));
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
            return redirect(routes.IndexController.index("Error while checking the Verison"));
        }
    }, httpExecutionContext.current());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `thenComposeAsync()` instead of `thenApplyAsync()`, and have your inner lambda also return a `CompletableFuture`:

```
public CompletionStage<Result> showDownloadScreen(String license_key) {
    return license_dao.getLicenseByKey(license_key).thenComposeAsync(license -> {
        try {
            if(license!=null) {
                if(license.isRegistered()) {
                    return version_dao.getVersionUntilX(license.getUpdates_until())
                        .toCompletableFuture()
                        .thenApply(v -> ok(views.html.download.render(license, v)));
                } else {
                    return CompletableFuture.completedFuture(redirect(routes.LicenseActivationController.showActivationScreen(license_key)));
                }
            } else {
                return CompletableFuture.completedFuture(redirect(routes.IndexController.index("Insert Key can not be found!")));
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
            return CompletableFuture.completedFuture(redirect(routes.IndexController.index("Error while checking the Verison")));
        }
    }, httpExecutionContext.current());
}
```

Since that lambda is quite complex, it would also be worth extracting it to a separate method, and do some more cleanup.